# Checking if bot is permitted to send and read messages in a channel discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I check if my bot is allowed to send and read messages in a specific channel? My code right now is:

```
channel = client.get_channel('''channel id''')
print(channel.permissions_for(client.user))
```

But the resulting error is in the abc.py part of discord and it says:

```
print(channel.permissions_for(client.user))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 146, in permissions_for
    base = super().permissions_for(member)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 486, in permissions_for
    roles = member._roles
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute '_roles'
```

Even though the bot does have the "bots" role. Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the [[has_permission]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) documentation and the [[permission_property]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Permissions) fully and clearly.
It will answer your queries!

Comment: Thank you for the resources! The thing is, I'm trying to make a direct command for my bot where users can tell the bot to direct its future messages to a specific channel. So I'd have to check the bots permissions for a specific channel within the command, and the only checks I could find were command decorators that don't specify a specific channel. Are there any functions that return the bots permissions in a text channel? Thanks!